# Finding product of roots of equation of unknown degree when a root is given

Tags: roots

> If $7^{\frac13} + 7^{\frac23}$ is a root of equation of minimum possible degree with rational coefficients, then what is the product of roots of this equation?

How do I solve it?

Comment: Are you familiar with Galois theory?

Comment: @AlexBecker No, it is a Tenth standard question...

Comment: Ah. Well I have no idea how to do it without some relatively heavy math then, except by explicitly computing powers.

Comment: $$y=7^{\frac13} + 7^{\frac23}\implies y^3=7+7^2+3\cdot 7^{\frac13}\cdot 7^{\frac23}y$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That was about to be my answer :(

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $y^3 = 56 + 21y$, So the equation of minimum degree will be $y^3 + 0y^2 - 21y - 56 = 0$, which means that our answer is 56...Thanks

Comment: @shauryagupta, have you meant sum or product ?

Comment: @shauryagupta, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas

Comment: @shauryagupta sum would be zero. See [vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'm sorry...I meant product! :)